# I need to use index the column of json data in mysql

Tags: mysql, json, indexing

My database is MySQL and I found that there isn't a JSON type but only text.  But in my situation, I need to store the data of JSON meaning and use index on the hash key of the JSON data.  So 'text' type isn't the right way.  By the way, I can't separate the JSON data into different columns, because I don't know what the keys are in the JSON.

What I really need is a solution for searching JSON data by the JSON keys in MySQL using index or sth, so the searching speed could be fast and acceptable.

Comment: Please don't sign your posts. That's what the badge things with your name and reputation are for. Unless your italic statement is actually part of the problem, in which case we cannot help you.

Comment: Could you post a formatted example JSON?

Comment: Or you could use PostgreSQL 9.4 (currently RC1), they support GIN for JSONB data :3

Answer (score 1):

If you can't normalize your data into a RDBMS-readable format, you should not use MySQL.

A noSQL database might be the better approach.
MySQLs strengths are to work with relational data.

You are trying to fit a square object through a round hole :)

Answer (score 0):

`select concat('{"objects\":['
               ,(select group_concat(
                       concat('{"id":"',id, '","field":"',field,'"}') separator ',') 
                from placeholder)
               ,']}');`

Anything more generic would require dynamic sql

Comment: What i really need is a solution for searching json data by the json keys using index or sth ,so the searching speed could be fast and accaptable.but still  really thaks for ur kindness.

Answer (score 0):

I think your situation calls for the [Levenshtein Distance algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). You basically need to do a text search of an unknown quantity (the haystack) with a text fragment (the needle). And you need it to be fast, because indexing is out of the question.

There is a little known (or little-used at any rate) capability of MySQL whereby you can create [User-Defined Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-udf.html). The function itself is a stored procedure, and for extra speed, it can be compiled in C++. UDF's are used natively in your queries as though they are part of regular MySQL syntax.

Here are the details for implementing a [Levenshtein User-Defined Function](http://samjlevy.com/2011/03/mysql-levenshtein-and-damerau-levenshtein-udfs/) in MySQL.

An example query might be...

```
SELECT json FROM my_table WHERE levenshtein('needle') < 5;
```

The `5` refers to the 'edit distance' and actually allows for near matches to be located.